# Pivot snowflake columns to rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table as below:

Just FYI i have over 200 columns in Key column i needed pivoted as final table.

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| column1 | abc |
| column2 | xyz |
| column3 | 123 |

The final table i would like to pivot is:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | xyz | 123 |

Original file came in avro format and it was loaded in snowflake as first table.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try using Pivot,  if you need to dynamically have the column names then you can use this link which has an example by Felipe Hoffa.
https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c

```
with data1 as 
(select 'column1' as key1 , 'abc' value1
union all select 'column2' as key1 , 'xyz'
union all select 'column3' as key1 , '123'
)
SELECT * from data1
pivot(max(key1 )for value1 in ('abc','xyz','123')) as p;

 PIVOT(SUM(amount) FOR MONTH IN ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR'))
      AS p
  ORDER BY EMPID;
```